# $\frac{dR}{dt}=\sqrt{\frac{\beta}{R}-k}$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to solve $$\dot{R}^2+k=\frac{8}{3}\pi G\rho R^2$$ for $\rho=\frac{B}{R^3}$, and $k\neq 0$.

For brevity let $\beta = \frac{8}{3}\pi G B$ so that $\dot{R}^2+k=\frac{\beta}{R}$. Then,
$$(\frac{dR}{dt})^2=\frac{\beta}{R}-k$$
$$\frac{dR}{dt}=\sqrt{\frac{\beta}{R}-k}$$

$$\int dt = t =\int{\frac{dR}{\sqrt{\frac{\beta}{R}-k}}}$$
And this is where i get stuck. I tried to clean it up by doing:
$$t=\int \frac{R^{1/2}dR}{\sqrt{\beta-kR}}$$
But this doesn't seem any better.

Comment: I don't know if it helps but you could rewrite your integrand as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\sqrt{ \frac{\beta}{\beta - kR} - 1 }$

Comment: Wolfram Dev Platform gives $$t=-\frac{\sqrt{R}\sqrt{\beta-kR}}{k}+\frac{\beta\arctan\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{kR}}{\sqrt{\beta-kR}}\right)}{k^{3/2}}. $$

Comment: Maybe some trigonometric substitution like $R = \frac{\beta}{k}(\sin u)^2$ could work?

Comment: Keister, I wonder how they arrived at that solution. I'd like to be able to show some work. Sobi, i like that idea. Lemme try with your edit (with the constants infront of the sin^2).

Comment: The substitution $R=x^2$ should be effective as a first step.

Comment: CAS like Maple says in parametric form solution:$[R \left( T \right) ={\frac {\beta}{{T}^{2}+k}},t \left( T \right) =-{
\frac {1}{{k}^{3/2} \left( {T}^{2}+k \right) } \left( \beta\, \left( {
T}^{2}+k \right) \arctan \left( {\frac {T}{\sqrt {k}}} \right) -{\it 
C1}\,{T}^{2}{k}^{3/2}+\beta\,T\sqrt {k}-{\it C1}\,{k}^{5/2} \right) }]
$

Comment: Yeah Sobi, that works. Unfortunately it seems that the transcendental solution is impossible to avoid. Oh well...

Comment: Mariusz, I like that solution for R(T). But that's not the same as R(t), right? I'm not familiar with "parametric form" solutions.

Comment: @IronCharioteer.No,not the same, `T` is a parameter,and `T` is not `t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the integral $$t=\int\frac{dR}{\sqrt{\frac{\beta}{R}-k}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\int\frac{dR}{\sqrt{\frac{\beta}{Rk}-1}}$$ you can make the substitution $$\frac{\beta}{Rk}=\sec^2\theta\implies dR=-\frac{2\beta}{k}\cos\theta\sin\theta$$

Then, $$t=-2\beta\sqrt{k}\int\cos^2\theta d\theta=-\beta\sqrt{k}(\theta+\sin\theta\cos\theta)$$

$$=-\beta\sqrt{k}\left[\arccos\sqrt{\frac{Rk}{\beta}}+\sqrt{\frac{Rk}{\beta}}\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{Rk}{\beta}\right)}\right]+c$$

Comment: I got the basically the same answer (except with arcsin instead of arccos) using Sobi's suggested substitution, R=b/k sin^2. Thanks David. :)

Comment: @IronCharioteer you are welcome